# Flot 0.8.2 Line Chart - Color Bug

Tags: javascript, json, graph, colors, flot

I was working with Flot line charts and setting their colors. I found an odd bug. After the first 3 colors, the plot uses the last color for all of the other lines. This is not the correct behavior.

[image]

What makes this even more interesting is that the legend displays the correct colors. Is this a known bug?

```
var dataSet = [
        {label: "d1", data: demand},
        {label: "d2", data: demand2},
        {label: "d3", data: demand3},
        {label: "d4", data: demand4},
        {label: "d5", data: demand5},
        {label: "d6", data: demand6}
    ]

$.plot(placeholder2, dataSet, {
    series: { 

    },
    legend: {
        noColumns: 0,
        position: "nw"
    },
    colors:["#2980B9","#D35400","#F39C12","#7F8CFF","#C0392B","#7F8C8D"]
});
```

Just to make sure that I wasn't going crazy, and to confirm, I tried the code again, but removed the colors specification. You'll see that even with Flot's default colors, the last color "sticks".
[image]

Comment: Is this question about the bug itself or how to work around it?

Comment: Luke, good point. I expect that the work around might also fix the bug. My expectation is that since the legend is getting the colors correctly, the plot is simply not iterating through the color list.

Comment: Are you experiencing the same behavior in stable release 0.8.1? If not, is there any reason that you *need* to use 0.8.2 (alpha) for your application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Looks like the bug was a result of how I had the code setup. When I removed the series:{} code, it seems to work correctly.

The bug may be my fault, but that kind of repetitive behavior might need to be looked into.

```
$.plot(placeholder2, dataSet, {
    legend: {
        noColumns: 0,
        position: "nw"
    },
    colors:["#2980B9","#D35400","#F39C12","#7F8CFF","#C0392B","#7F8C8D"]
});
```

Comment: Yeah, I think I would submit a bug report on that one.